# getContent returns PDF that consists of blank pages

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I have a Visualforce page that generates a PDF document (it contains renderAs="pdf"). If I use the URL of the page directly and supply some parameters, it works brilliantly. Embedded images, the Arial font, even a page break (done with CSS).

But: if I try to get this PDF using Pagereference ... getContent(), I always get a PDF with 2 blank pages. The number of bytes are correct, the font is correct, but the contents are blank.

I have tried a lot: set the font, the color, ... The method that calls getContent() is a synchronous method, I think that is important, because there are some constraints. Googling shows people with the same problem, but so far, no solution helps my particular situation.

The code of the page as it is per 2016-01-19:

```
<apex:page id="authorizationForm" language="!$CurrentPage.parameters.language}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false">
<head>
<style type="text/CSS">
  @page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 25mm;
  }
  body {
    font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
    font-size: 11px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>


Things with <apex:outputText> etc.

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

The code that performs the getContent() as it is per 2016-01-19:

```
RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
PageReference authorizationForm = Page.AuthorizationForm;
res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
Blob pdfBody = authorizationForm.getContentAsPdf();
res.statusCode = 200;
res.responseBody = pdfBody;
```

Comment: have you tried getContentAspdf() method? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm

Comment: Hi Sander, can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? Are you just trying to give users a way to download the correct PDF? In that case I think an `apex:outputLink` using URLFOR() should work for you.

Comment: 1. Are the pages completely blank or it contains the static text but values from objects/controllers are not populating on the pdf? 2. Where are you calling the getContent from.. a controller or a trigger?

Comment: @Ratan Yes, there is no difference between getContent and getContentAsPDF

Comment: @MartyC. We do not want to give the user a Salesforce URL. Don't ask, it's complicated. We want to give a complete PDF, no download link.

Comment: @AAU 1. They are completely blank. Ctrl-A Ctrl-C is not able to capture anything either. 2. It is from an Apex class that is invoked by a REST method. We have implemented a webservice in Salesforce.

Comment: @SanderdeJong, I think understand what you're doing in your Visualforce pages. It seems that you have one page responsible for producing the PDF, which uses `renderAsPdf="true"`. Is your second page responsible for presenting the PDF using `renderAsPdf="false"`?

Comment: @MartyC. I think we have a misunderstanding. I only have 1 VF page. That's the Apex/HTML one for which I gave the source code.

Comment: @SanderdeJong, I'm confused... If you only have one page, which appears to be working fine to produce the PDF, why do you show the Apex with `authorizationForm.getContent()`? Are you trying to put that into an attachment, or somewhere else?

Comment: @MartyC. Because the PDF needs to be returned as the result of a REST call. So the PDF is put in the result body of the REST call.

Comment: @SanderdeJong that makes sense. In that case are you serving that content out via HTTP or HTTPS? If so, are you specifying the correct [Content-Type header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) [for PDFs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-media-type-for-pdf-files)?

Comment: @MartyC. Thanks for that! I am going to experiment with those settings. Right now, I'm just relying on the default (not setting them explicitly).

Comment: So I did some more experiments today. By now I have exhausted all options that I know of. For example, the VF page now produces an HTML page, which I turn into a Blob with getContentAsPdf. Same results. The Content-type is now application/pdf, which is what I wanted. Doesn't matter. Only thing left is experimenting with UTF-8, but I don't understand that stuff. The output is a PDF file, but its contents look to be of a wrong encoding. How could I fix this?

Comment: I think it would be useful if you could update your question with the latest code you have, including the REST service, I'm not clear if you're using getContent or getContentAsPDF. If you could update your question that would be great.

Comment: @PhilHawthorn Updated both code sections.

Comment: @SanderdeJong
Have you tried Base64 encoding the response, as suggested in 
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50371/sending-a-pdf-from-salesforce-through-a-rest-call

Comment: @joe That is indeed the trick. Sorry, I can't award the bounty to a commenter.

Comment: @SanderdeJong Glad that it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your updated question. I'm not sure what you're doing with the response object. Here's a little test that I just did which might give you some food for thought:

**Visualforce:**

```
<apex:page id="authorizationForm" language="!$CurrentPage.parameters.language}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/CSS">
  @page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 25mm;
  }
  body {
    font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
    font-size: 11px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>


Things with apex:outputText etc.

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex REST:**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/TestPDF/') 
global class TestRestPDF 
{
    @HttpGet
    global static String getPdf()
    {
        Blob pdf = new PageReference('/apex/authorizationForm').getContentAsPDF();
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdf);
    }
}
```

The REST service basically returns a Base64 encoded String representing the PDF. You would then need to decode that in your client app to reconstruct the PDF. You could also generate the PDF directly from the response of the method, for example if you were to paste this in its entirety to your browser URL you'd get a PDF on screen:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,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
```

What is your client application? i.e. the application calling your REST service?

This also appears to return correctly:

```
global class TestRestPDF 
{
    @HttpGet
    global static void getPdf()
    {
        Blob pdf = new PageReference('/apex/authorizationForm').getContentAsPDF();

        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        RestContext.response.responseBody = pdf;
    }
}
```

Though, I can only see the RAW response, it may well be worth converting to Base64 first, e.g.:

```
RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdf));
```

Comment: Thanks, the crucial part is doing Blob.valueOf(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdf)) instead of just pdf. Kudos also to joe, whose comment pointed to the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm admittedly not an expert in PDF content delivery, but your requirement for not giving users a Salesforce URL and instead displaying the PDF in read-only format lends itself to one of two options (I think):

1. Use [UrlRewriter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm) to obscure the Salesforce URL, and perhaps create a custom object (e.g., PdfDelivery__c) to track the parameters of each PDF generation request.
2. Use a secure container like what Salesforce uses for its [content deliveries](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=content_delivery_about.htm&language=en).